# Rewrite Wordpress Custom Post Type URL

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-post-type

I’m creating a hotel booking site plugin in WordPress. I use custom post types for the hotels and rooms. Since most hotels have similar room names, I would like to rewrite the URL for the rooms so the hotel name is also included. For example:

> `http://abookingsite.com/hotels/hilton-hotel/standard-room`

`hilton-hotel` is the title of the `hotels` post type and `standard-room` is the `rooms` post type.

Any ideas if this can be done?

Thanks