# Custom post type permalink shows blog/ in the single page

Tags: wordpress, blogs, permalinks

I have created a custom post type and it permalink shows blog/ into the single page,
For eg : www.example.com/blog/event/wine-tasting/

I need this blog/ to be removed from the single page URL and it should come like,
www.example.com/event/wine-tasting/

Comment: What CMS are you using? Or where are you doing this? Are you using .htaccess to rewrite URLs? Need a bit more clarification.

Comment: I am using wordpress CMS and the default custom post permalink generates with blog/ URL. Not using any rewrite rule in functions.php also not redirecting via .htaccess.

Answer (score 4):

I did some research and came up with this post:

> When you register the custom post type, you have to specify that the
>   rewrite rule shouldn't be prepended with the existing URL structure.
>
> In short, this means that this line in your register_post_type call:
>
> `'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'projects')`, should turn into this:
>
> `'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'projects','with_front' => false)`, For
>   more info, check out the rewrite argument from the codex entry on
>   register_post_type
>
> edit: just make sure that, after updating the code, you flush the
>   rewrite rules by visiting Settings > Permalinks. Otherwise you'll
>   still see the old links. - andreiio

Also found these 3 resources that may help you if you get stumped from another question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21374715/rewrite-wordpress-custom-post-type-url) - by Sophia:

[WordPress.org Topic](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-post-type-rewrite-permalink-and-exclude-base)

[TutsPlus](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/the-rewrite-api-post-types-taxonomies/)

[Another Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53298/custom-post-type-url-rewriting)